# Add lombok plugin to multimodule gradle build

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin, multi-module

I have 3 projects, build with Gradle (8.6), that I wanted to share dependencies and plugins. To do so, I've created a multi module build with buildSrc. I try to follow documentations and schema generated with Gradle and using convetion plugins. However, I cannot add any plugins (including lombok) beside 'java' plugin.

My goal was that I wanted to create a "common" project where other modules can get dependencies and plugins from.

I was able to recreate problem when using standard schema generated with 'Gradle init'.

My confing looks like this:

buildSrc/java-common.conventions:

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 */

plugins {
    // Apply the java Plugin to add support for Java.
    id 'java'
    id 'io.freefair.lombok'                 //Lombok project
}

repositories {
    // Use Maven Central for resolving dependencies.
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    constraints {
        // Define dependency versions as constraints
        implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.9'
    }

    // Use JUnit Jupiter API for testing.
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.2'

    // Use JUnit Jupiter Engine for testing.
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    // Use junit platform for unit tests.
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

buildSrc/java.application.conventions.gradle

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 */

plugins {
    // Apply the common convention plugin for shared build configuration between library and application projects.
    id 'com.temp.java-common-conventions'

    // Apply the application plugin to add support for building a CLI application in Java.
    id 'application'
}
```

app/build.gradle

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 */

plugins {
    id 'com.temp.java-application-conventions'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-text'
    implementation project(':utilities')
}

application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainClass = 'com.temp.app.App'
}
```

And error that I get:

```
Build file 'C:\Temp\GradleExample\app\build.gradle' line: 6

An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.temp.java-application-conventions']
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.temp.java-application-conventions'.
   > Failed to apply plugin 'com.temp.java-common-conventions'.
      > org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin with id 'io.freefair.lombok' not found.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Comment: Why did you add a plugin `io.freefair.lombok`?

Comment: @dan1stiscrying I wanted to use it in all my projects

Comment: Plugins that are not bundled with Gradle need a version. See the [FreeFair plugin page](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/io.freefair.lombok) for an example.

Comment: @BjørnVester When I add a version, then it says that "invalid plugin request [id: 'io.freefair.lombok', version: '8.6']. Plugin requests from precompiled scripts must not include a version number."

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that it was used as a precompiled script. You still need the version number though, as Gradle must be able to download it from the plugin portal. The difference is that here it needs to be on the script classpath instead. Try creating a build.gradle file in the buildSrc folder, with a dependency block that includes the module (with the group and name being the same as in the description from the "legacy plugin" from the link).